# linux mput command options

Tags: ftp, command-line-interface

I'm ftp-ing files to another server via command line.

To put multiple files I need to use the "mput" command.

```
 #ftp> mput *.php
```

However, it continuously asks me to verify if I want to put every single file, one by one.
Is there an option that forces yes?  And if a file already exists, to also force over-writing the pre-existing file on the remote server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn off the verification by entering 'prompt' - that toggles prompt mode on and off, and it's on by default.

I *think* that with prompt off it will over-write files with the same name, but I'm not sure.